# Is SE search broken?

Tags: bug, search

Until I used the actual Search box on SE sites, I thought their searching was absolute genius.

I was excited to see a search plugin for SE sites, and added it to my browser.

But every time I search on anything other than a word or two I get no results, even when results definitely exist, e.g. on drupal.stackexchange.com:

e.g. Here's the search results (or lack of):
[image: screenshot 1 - no results, apparently]

vs. exactly the same text plugged in as if to start a question:
[image: screenshot 2 - results!]

I don't know if this is a bug or the lack of a very important feature?

Comment: It is a *feature* that search for duplicate questions works better then normal search...